get_param of Bus Selector is too slow
I generate a Simulink model programmatically which means that I change the name of the signals at bus selector inports.
In order to reconfigure the bus selector after programmatically changing the model I get all input signals from the Bus Selector block, join the signal names and provide them again to the Bus Selector output :
list_input_signals = get_param(bus_selector_handle,'InputSignals');
input_signals_str = strjoin(list_input_signals , ',');
set_param(bus_selector_handle,'OutputSignals',input_signals_str )

This is based on an answer on Mathwork's forum here : https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/772493-select-bus-elements-programmatically
It works but the get_param instruction is painfully slow. It is taking up 99% of the execution time of the three lines according to Matlab's profiler. It represents around 15s for 250 bus selector blocks and it scales too much for bigger models.
Is there a more efficient way to refresh the Bus Selector block or to access all input signals to replace the incrimated get_param ?
I tried the following workaround but with the same issue :
ph = get_param(bus_selector_handle, 'PortHandles');
sh = get_param(ph.Inport, 'SignalHierarchy');
input_signals_str = strjoin({sh.Children.SignalName},',');
set_param(bus_selector_handle,'OutputSignals',input_signals_str )

